# How to get the the seek time while on video playing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm trying to get the seek time while on video playing. I use the play event it is triggered only video start.

HTML:

```
<video controls id="videoFile">
   <source src="Why Linux over Windows 3D Animation.mp4" id="video_here"> 
</video>
```

Javasript:

```
var secondvideo = document.getElementById('videoFile');
secondvideo.addEventListener('play', function(e) { 
    // The video is playing
    console.log("current time= "+ document.getElementById('videoFile').currentTime);

});
```

Comment: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html#MethodscurrentTime

Comment: I want the event name to get the seek time while on video playing.

Comment: Here you can find HTML5 Video Events and API: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
secondvideo.addEventListener("timeupdate",
   function (ev) {
      console.log(ev.target.currentTime);
   });
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#handler-mediacontroller-ontimeupdate

Here you can find HTML5 Video Events and API: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: Thanks. It does trigger properly.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime):

> The `HTMLMediaElement.currentTime` property gives the current playback
>   time in seconds. Setting this value seeks the media to the new time.

Based on this information, you should do something like the following:

```
var secondvideo = document.getElementById('videoFile');
secondvideo.addEventListener('play', function(e) { 
    // The video is playing
    console.log("Playing video");
    console.log(secondvideo.currentTime);
});
secondvideo.addEventListener('pause', function(e) { 
    // The video is paused
    console.log("Paused video");
    console.log(secondvideo.currentTime);
});
secondvideo.addEventListener('seeking', function(e) { 
    // The user seeked a new timestamp in playback
    console.log("Seeking in video");
    console.log(secondvideo.currentTime);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.seeking event is not trigger.

Comment: @santho I tested this on Firefox and it does trigger properly whenever the user seeks a new timestamp in the playback.